# How to ensure every key is represented in all Beam partitions

Tags: python, apache-beam

I'm putting together a python Apache Beam pipeline to run on Dataflow. This pipeline assembles a `PCollection` of TensorFlow `TFExamples` to ultimately be saved into `TFRecords` using the built-in `tfrecordio` API.

I want to partition my data into three pieces: training (80%), validation (10%), and testing (10%). Ideally, I would like to be able to assign the elements for each label round-robin so that a specific split is enforced and isn't left to random chance. The *non-beam* code for achieving this would look something like:

```
distribution_schedule = [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] # train = 0, valid = 1, test = 2

class ExampleDistributor():
    def __init__(self):
        self.examples_per_label = {}
    def assign(label_example_pair):
        label_examples = self.examples_per_label.get(label_example_pair[0], 0)
        return = distribution_schedule[label_examples % len(distribution_schedule)]
        self.examples_per_label[label] = label_examples + 1
```

This would assign, on a per-label basis, the first element to validation, the second to testing, the third through tenth to training, then repeat until exhausted. If I had only three examples (not realistic, but just for example) then each partition would get exactly one. Alternatively, if I had 999 examples then 100 would go to validation, 100 to testing, and 799 to training. This is how Google's AutoML service distributes examples, and I am trying to do the same. This would also allow me to change the schedule to enforce a different distribution.

Like I said, that is my *ideal* case. Alternatively, I would also be content with a mechanism that used random assignment (as most do) **but guaranteed that every partition received at least one example**.

I know the simple solution would be to do use a simple randomizer lambda in a Partition transform, but I don't like how there will always be a chance- however small it may be- that a group could have zero examples for a label.

How can I ensure that every partition will have *at least* one example of every label? Furthermore, if it's possible with beam, how can I make a round-robin beam transform? I figure it could involve a `GroupByKey` transform to group examples by label, but after that how can I make sure that every partition has examples?

Answer (score 1):

With any reasonably sized data set, the random partitioning should essentially never result in empty partitions.  Given that, the simplest thing to do would be to add a check that each partition has at least one element (with random partitioning), and fail the pipeline if not.  Something like

```
partitions = input
| 'Partition' >> beam.Partition(...)

def checkNonZero(n):
  if n == 0:
    raise Exception('...')
  return n

for partition in partitions:
  partition
  | 'Count' >> beam.combiners.Count.Globally()
  | 'Check non-zero' >> beam.Map(checkNonZero)

# process partitions normally here
```

Comment: Thank you. Realistically speaking I agree with you, but I am still curious if this can be done. I came up with a pattern using GroupIntoBatches that I thought would work, but hit a snag. If you're curious, you can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65526982/1500134